# How to change link colour using CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm playing with link colours and am struggling over one particular issue.

My CSS code is:

```
a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  colour: white;
}

a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: purple;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #C0C0C0;
}
```

Everything is functioning perfectly, except that the default link colour isn't changing.  The hover and visited colours are changing as per the commands, I can add or remove underlines from the default link style, I can change the colour of the default text background, and it all works just fine.  It's just the text colour of the default link that I seem unable to manipulate.  I have tried using just a: instead of  a:link but that makes no difference.  If I use the old

```
<body link="white">
```

technique then the default colour changes as required, but I need to do this in CSS.

Can anyone suggest why just this one function isn't working for me?

Answer (score 9):

You have a typo:

```
colour: white;
```

Should be:

```
color: white;
```

Comment: Unless you feel like running [Spiffing-CSS](http://www.phpkode.com/scripts/item/spiffing-css/), for `writing CSS in well-spoken English` :)

Comment: @ChristoferEliasson - I say!

Comment: Excuse me while I die of embarrassment.  I've wasted a whole bloody morning over this, and I used to be a proofreader!

Comment: @user1806216 - We say po-tay-toe, you say po-ta-to.